# How to stop Safari from rotating my gradient?

Tags: css, gradient

I have a gradient which renders a small 1px striped background. This works fine in Firefox. But when i try to implement it with -webkit-linear-gradient i need two different rotation values for safari and chrome. Safari renders it just right with 127deg which is 8deg off.

```
/* renders correct in firefox (20.0) */
-moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #FFF 45%, #DDD 45%, #DDD 58%, #FFF 58%, #FFF 100%);
/* renders right in safari (6.0.4) */
-webkit-linear-gradient(127deg, #FFF 0%, #FFF 46%, #DDD 46%, #DDD 55%, #FFF 55%, #FFF 100%);
/* renders almost right in chrome (26) */
-webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #FFF 0%, #FFF 46%, #DDD 46%, #DDD 55%, #FFF 55%, #FFF 100%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frog32/CBZav/2/

Is there a way to render such small gradients or should i use a background image?

Comment: The best way might be to just use an image of what you are looking for in the background and repeat it